# Getting Name error while calling two functions at a time Using Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting name error "NameError: name 'id_count2' is not defined" while calling two functions at a time where the code needs to be corrected this is my code

```
import numpy as np
op_col = []
for i in df1['Speed']:
 op_col.append(i)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
x=np.array([ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  8,
       14, 14, 14, 14, 11, 11,  8, 11, 12, 14,  9,  8, 13, 15,  7, 11, 13,
       11,  1,  1,  0,  0, 13,  9, 14,  8,  9, 10, 19,  8, 11, 11, 13, 16,
        8,  0,  0,  7, 14, 15, 12,  8,  0, 10,  9,  8,  0,  0,  9,  9,  7,
        7, 11, 13, 12, 11,  7, 12, 16, 16, 15,  0,  0,  8, 13, 12, 10, 10,
       10, 11, 13, 14,  7, 11, 13, 17,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10,  7,  7,  9, 10,
        8,  9, 10,  7,  8,  7, 10, 10, 12, 13,  9,  8, 12,  9,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0, 11, 11, 14,  9, 16, 26, 23,  9, 16, 19,  7,  0,  2,  0, 12,
       16, 15, 16, 17, 15, 12, 12, 15, 21, 25, 27, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28,  7,
       10, 12, 14, 17,  0,  0,  0, 10, 10, 12,  7, 12, 16, 20, 18,  7, 18])
x1=x.astype("int32")
x2=x.astype("int32")
def get_count1(id_count1):
 x1=x.astype("int32")
 sub_lists = np.split(x1, np.where(np.diff(x1)<0)[0] + 1)
 id_count1 = 0
 id_list1= []
 for unit in sub_lists:
    if min(unit)<=5 and max(unit) >12 and max(unit) <28 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
        id_count1+= 1
        id_list1.append(unit)
 return id_count1
def get_count2(id_count2):
 x2=x.astype("int32")
 sub_lists = np.split(x2, np.where(np.diff(x2)<0)[0] + 1)
 id_count2 = 0
 id_list2= []
 for unit in sub_lists:
    if min(unit)<=5 and max(unit) >16 and max(unit) <28 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
        id_count2+= 1
        id_list2.append(unit)
 return id_count2
```

by calling first function get_count1(id_count1)gives me the output calling second function gives error def get_count2(id_count2): `NameError: name 'id_count2' is not defined`
thanks in adavance

Comment: Why are `id_count1` and `id_count2` parameters? You never used the parameter values, you assign `0` to them at the beginning of each function.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is due to the fact that you are trying to pass the variable `id_count2` as an argument to the `get_count2()` function, but it has not been defined yet.

To fix this, you can simply remove `id_count2` from the argument list of the `get_count2()` function.

```
def get_count2():
x2=x.astype("int32")
sub_lists = np.split(x2, np.where(np.diff(x2)<0)[0] + 1)
id_count2 = 0
id_list2= []
for unit in sub_lists:
    if min(unit)<=5 and max(unit) >16 and max(unit) <28 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
        id_count2+= 1
        id_list2.append(unit)
return id_count2

id_count2 = get_count2()
```

Comment: same error only i am getting by changing the code also

Comment: Try

id_count2 = 0
def get_count2(id_count2):
 x2=x.astype("int32")
 sub_lists = np.split(x2, np.where(np.diff(x2)<0)[0] + 1)
 id_count2 = 0
 id_list2= []
 for unit in sub_lists:
    if min(unit)<=5 and max(unit) >16 and max(unit) <28 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
        id_count2+= 1
        id_list2.append(unit)
 return id_count2

Comment: @AparnaAppu how are you calling `get_count2(id_count2)`? What is the value of `id_count2`?